# BASH/AWK how in a given text file replace all dates dd.mm.yyyy dates to dd month yy

Tags: bash, awk

as in the topic how to in given text file using bash/awk replace in file only dates in format date dd.mm.yyyy to date format dd month yyyy where month (like 02 to february etc)

input file:

```
kandal w Rosji. "Polacy są niezbyt kreatywni 12.12.2032
43.12.4521 Dramatyczne wyznanie córki gen. Jaruzelskiego
Politycy chcą,
23/32/3211 by Tusk przeprosił Benedykta XVI
Nie żyje wybitny historyk prof. Andrzej Garlicki
Polityk PiS: Śląsk należy przywrócić Polsce
```

Comment: Which step are you having trouble with: extracting dates of the form `dd.mm.yyyy` or converting such a date to `dd month yyyy`?

Comment: first i have no idea how to get to a file
i know how to do something in given directory but not file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use gnu awk's (gawk) time capabilities like this:

```
echo "18.11.2012" | awk -F"." '{t=mktime($3 " " $2 " " $1 " 00 00 00");
     print strftime("%d %B %Y", t)}'
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/Jmz77N

Use FS instead of -F as you want:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS="."} {t=mktime($3 " " $2 " " $1 " 00 00 00"); 
     print strftime("%d %B %Y", t)}'
```

#### UPDATE: (script to work with your input file)

```
awk '{
  for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
     if ($i ~ /[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\.[1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/) {
        split($i, a, ".");
        t=mktime(a[3] " " a[2] " " a[1] " 00 00 00");
        if (t == -1)
           printf("%s", $i);
        else
           printf("%s", strftime("%d %B %Y", t));
     }
     else
        printf("%s", $i);
    if (i<NF)
       printf(" ");        
   } 
   printf("\n");
}' inputFile
```

#### New Demo: http://ideone.com/PoMsU3

Comment: and i begin with this ? do take file as input ?
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 1 ] || [ ! -f $1 ]
then
  echo give text file as input
  exit 1
fi

Comment: also i havent permision to use -F

Comment: @Vardius: Answer is to show you how to do the task as you've asked in your question. Feel free to pass in a file and run above awk script on an input file.

Comment: and how to i get a specific date in that form dd.mm.yyyy from text file now ?

Comment: @Vardius: If you can paste small snippet of your input file in your question, I can help you out.

Comment: i seen but i need also how to get date from text file now. i got something like this to check if input is a file
`#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 1 ] || [ ! -f $1 ]
then
  echo give textfile as input
  exit 1
fi` is it correct ? and what next?

Comment: You have all kind of weird dates in input file like `43.12.4521` and `23/32/3211` etc. What do you want to do about that?

Comment: `43.12.4521` is in `nn.nn.nnnn` format but it is an invalid date? What to do abt this?

Comment: i jsut type random number for exmaple dont worry about that xD
it can be invalid becous it wont be in the text file i will get
it just about the way to select it (all dates in that format)

Comment: Ok give me few mins I will provide you a file parsing script for that.

Comment: thanks. another thing is i have no idea if i will have to display only dates in changed format or all text with changed format dates

Comment: it works fine but it cut the spaces and when i put date like this (25.01.4521 it display 1 january 1970 and it cut ()
you can try this as an input `tekst1 12.12.2032 tekst1
tekst3 (25.01.4521) tekst4 26.02.4521 TEKST5
GFHGHFGH
23/03/3211`

Comment: As I said 25.01.4521 is a bogus date and you wrote: `i jsut type random number for exmaple dont worry about that xD`.

Comment: i didnt know that i will get something like this from my teacher. sorry
and its not about the year 4521 but about a date in ()

Comment: ok check the final edit now and check the latest live demo as well.

Comment: but it didnt change the format of date in () and it has to be changed

Comment: try with this input
`tekst1 12.12.2032 tekst1 tekst3 (25.01.4521) tekst4 26.02.4521 TEKST5 GFHGHFGH 23/03/3211`

Comment: Did you see the demo or not?